# The meaning of Dictionary`2 in a stack trace

Tags: c#, stack-trace

Sometimes I see this `` `2 `` in a stack trace. For example:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>          at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)

What is the meaning of `` `2 `` after Dictionary?

Comment: **'2** means *two* generic parameters in `Dictionary`s declaration: `Dictionary<K, V>`

Comment: Oh wow, escaping a leading ` is hard in SO-markdown ...

Comment: You can, you need double ` to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 `` means that the type is `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`, with two type arguments. So in this case it means that the type is `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, as we all know it.

Comment: One small doubt,the class Dictionary is defined by `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` then why it is needed to specify `2` [for *with two type arguments*] is it possible to use `1` or `3` instead?  as per my knowledge a list is specified as `System.Collections.Generic.List`1`.

Comment: Because that is the syntax for generics type arguments that CIL uses. Correct on the name.

Comment: @un-lucky I could also assume classes, that have a variable number of generic arguments. Consider `Func` for example (which is a `delegate`, however I assume this applies to classes also). It has a big list of generic arguments, reaching from `Func<TResult>` to `Func<T1, ..., T8, TResult>`.

Answer (score 6):

This's the way .Net makes classes' names. The initial declaration

```
 Dictionary<K, V>
```

will be turned into `Dictionary'2` type name where `'2` means **two** generic parameters:

```
 // Dictionary`2 - two generic parameters
 Console.WriteLine(typeof(Dictionary<int, string>).Name);

 // List`1 - one generic parameter
 Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<int>).Name);
```

Please compare:

```
 // IDictionary`2 - two generic parameters
 Console.WriteLine(typeof(IDictionary<int, string>).Name);

 // IDictionary - no generic parameters
 Console.WriteLine(typeof(System.Collections.IDictionary).Name);
```